# php find common keys in assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array

```
  "a" => array:99 [▶]
  "b" => array:98 [▶]
  "c" => array:98 [▶]
  "d" => array:98 [▶]
  "e" => array:98 [▶]
  "f" => array:98 [▶]
  "g" => array:97 [▶]
  "h" => array:72 [▶]
```

.....

I need to filter the arrays by common keys. array a has 99 items and h has 72 items so I need to make all the arrays in this array the same 72 items based on the key.

array a:

```
"Johnson" => "2.94"
"Jordan" => "1.99"
"Bob" => "3.29"
"Bill" => "2.60"
"Jon" => "3.82"
```

......

array b:

```
"Johnson" => "2.94"
"Jordan" => "1.99"
"Bob" => "3.29"
"Bill" => "2.60"
"Steve" => "3.82"
```

......

so I essentially want the arrays a and b to be:

```
"Johnson" => "2.94"
"Jordan" => "1.99"
"Bob" => "3.29"
"Bill" => "2.60"
```

because these are the keys that are consistent across those 2 arrays.

I would need each of the arrays to have the same items based on the key that exists in all of the arrays.

Is there a way to do this if the arrays are part of the same array?

Comment: what does "I need to make all the arrays in this array the same 72 items based on the key" mean ?

Comment: its an assoc array. Array a has 99 items and array h has 72 items array d has 98 items. So i need all the arrays to have the same items based on the common keys for all the arrays. So in the end all the arrays a-h would have 72 items or less.

Comment: Use `array_intersect_key`

Comment: Yes but they aren't 2 separate arrays. The arrays a-b-c-d are arrays where I want to find the elements of the arrays in a-b-c-d with common keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) once with all the subarrays passed to it. This you can do with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php): this will give you the result for the first item in your data. It will only have the keys remaining that also occur in all other items.

Then map the data with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) by applying again `array_intersect_key` to intersect each item with that first item's result.

Assuming your input is stored in a variable named `$data`:

```
$first = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key', $data);
$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($first) {
    return array_intersect_key($item, $first);
}, $data);
```

`$result` will have a copy of the data where each item will have the same keys (but still with their proper values of course).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of [`array_reduce`](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-reduce.php) & [`array_intersect_key`](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-intersect-key.php) (@Barmar).

```
$array = [  /* Your multidimensional array */  ];

$initial = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);

$consistentValues = array_reduce($array, function($result, $value) {
    return array_intersect_key($result, $value);
}, $initial);
```